# oracle 12c installation windows 10 exit on first cmd screen

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, installation, oracle12c

When installing oracle 12c (and also 11g) on a windows 10 machine the installation exits after the first cmd screen. It pops up for a brief moment and disappears. I tried the same installation on a clean windows 10 machine an it starts properly (so nothing wrong with the installation file). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

ONLY Oracle 12c (12.1.0.2) supported on Windows 10.
All full information about the compatibility of Oracle versions and supported platforms should be found on the official oracle support site.https://support.oracle.com

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As I mentioned I am able to do the installation on a clean installation of windows. I've fixed this issue with a virtual box but wasn't able to fix the problem in the other environment.